# Probability of a dice game?

Tags: probability

The question is as follows,

> A game consists of throwing 3 dice simultaneously. If number 1 or number 6 appears, the player wins $\$1$ else player loses $\$3$. After 9 games, what is the amount the player has won or lost?

I'm trying to bend my head trying all sorts of possibilities, can someone please point me towards the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Just a clarification, you should be interested in the 'expected amount the player has won or lost', because this is a random process and it's impossible to know **exactly** what is going to happen

Comment: The net gain in 9 games is a *random variable*, say $X$. You might want to know the *expected value* of $X$, or perhaps the *most probable value(s)* , etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of winning one game is $1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3=\frac{19}{27}$.

We can model each throw as a bernoulli r.v, $T_i\sim Ber\left(\frac{19}{27}\right)$. The distribution of the number wins in nine rolls ($W_9$)  will be Binomial:

$$ W_9 \sim Bin\left(9,\frac{19}{27}\right)$$

To get your winnings (losses), we can map each $T_i$ to the monetary result:

$$T_i \to M_i: \{0,1\} \mapsto \{-3,1\}$$

Based on the above, your winnings $C_9$ is a random variable:

$$C_9=W_9 - 3(9-W_9)=4W_9-27 \implies \frac{C_9+27}{4} \sim Bin\left(9,\frac{19}{27}\right)$$

So, $C_9$ is just a shifted and scaled binomial distribution. As others have pointed out:

$$E[C_9]=4E[W_9]-27 = -1.67$$

---

As an aside, while the expected value is negative, your probability of at least breaking even is:

$$P(C_9\geq 0) = P\left(W_9\geq \lceil \frac{27}{4}\rceil=7\right)\approx 20\%$$

Not that great.

Comment: It's a slightly interesting fact that although the "expected value" is **negative** (i.e., $−5/3$), the *most probable* value (i.e., the "mode") is **positive**: $mode(C_9) = 4⋅mode(Bin\left(9,\frac{19}{27}\right))−27=4⋅7−27=+1$.

Comment: @r.e.s. you got me interested in the overall probability of at least breaking even. Its not great.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a $1$ or $6$ does *not* appear in one throw of a standard die is $\frac 23$. Therefore the probability that the $1$ or $6$ does not appear in any of three throws is $\left(\frac 23\right)^3=\frac 8{27}$.

Therefore the expectation on one roll of the three dice is

$$1\cdot\left(1-\frac 8{27}\right)-3\left(\frac 8{27}\right)$$
$$=-\frac 5{27}$$

The expected value after $9$ rounds is then

$$9\cdot -\frac 5{27}=-\frac{45}{27}$$

So the player has the expectation of losing $$\approx \$1.67$$

As the comments say, this is the *expected* or *average* loss. The actual loss will vary.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that after $9$ games the player has won $\$9$ dollars, or has lost $\$27$ dollars, so there is no real answer to your question. You probably mean to ask what the player may *expect* to have won.

For $i=1,2,\dots,9$ let $X_i$ denotes what the player wins/looses in game $i$.

So $X_i=1$ if a number $1$ or $6$ appears and $X_i=-3$ otherwise.

Then after $9$ games his profit equals:$$X:=X_1+\cdots+X_9$$ Expectation is linear so:$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EX_1+\cdots+\mathbb EX_9$$ Evidently $\mathbb EX_i=\mathbb EX_1$ for each $i$, so:$$\mathbb EX=9\mathbb EX_1$$

What remains is finding $\mathbb EX_1$.

See the answer of Rory for that.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's work out the probability of having at least one 1 or one 6.

Throwing three dice, the total number of outcomes is 6^3=216. The probability of having no 1s and no 6s is (4/6)^3, so the probability of winning any particular game is 1- (4/6)^3, which is about .703.

So the expected outcome from one game is (.703)(1) + (.297)(-3) = -.188.

So after 8 games, the expected amount you'll have lost is -1.692$.

Comment: $1-(4/6)^3$, rounded to three decimal places, is $.704$. Using that would give a better final answer.

Comment: You're right, my fault for writing that in a hurry :)